# Overhead of moving executors between jobs in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading a [paper about job scheduling in Spark](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.01963), and I am confused about their overview of Spark:

> A Spark job consists of a DAG whose nodes are the execution stages of the job. Each stage represents an operation that the system runs in parallel over many shards of the stage’s input data. The inputs are the outputs of one or more parent stages, and each shard is pro- cessed by a single task. A stage’s tasks become runnable as soon as all parent stages have completed. How many tasks can run in parallel depends on the number of executors that the job holds. Usually, a stage has more tasks than there are executors, and the tasks therefore run in several “waves”. Executors are assigned by the Spark master based on user requests, and **by default stick to jobs until they finish. However, Spark also supports dynamic allocation of executors based on the wait time of pending tasks [9], although moving executors between jobs incurs some overhead (e.g., to tear down and launch JVMs).**

The Spark [Job Scheduling](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html) docs mention static vs. dynamic allocation of executors between *applications*, so it sounds like they are mixing up jobs and applications. At the same time, they correctly identify that a job is a DAG of stages, and they later mention that they restrict their study to job scheduling within a single application. And why would there be an overhead to "move executors between jobs"? Do the JVM's actually need to restart for that? [Tuning Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-locality) doesn't mention anything about this overhead.

I would appreciate some clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I looked through some of their source code for context clues, and believe that they implicitly assume that there is one job per application. This means that moving executors between jobs implies moving them between applications, which incurs overhead.

This assumption is not true in general, as jobs can be launched from multiple threads in a single application, so I wish they would have stated the assumption explicitly.